# How do access a list of directories stored in a variable in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm totally new to python and I'm trying to get a script that I've cobbled together to work.  Basically, I have a directory with about 50 subdirectories. I'm trying to get my script to:
1. store all of the subdir names in a list

2. create a set of folders within each subdir (i.e. subdir/folder1, folder2, etc.)
3. Go into each subdir and move files that are in the subdirs into the newly created folders within the subdirs (i.e. subdir/folder1/file1.ext, file2.ext)

I get the following error when running my script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./wsfonts.py", line 20, in <module>
    os.makedirs(os.path.join(root_dir,folder),exist_ok=True)
   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/posixpath.py", line 89, in join
     genericpath._check_arg_types('join', a, *p)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/genericpath.py", line 143, in 
  _check_arg_types
    (funcname, s.__class__.__name__)) from None
TypeError: join() argument must be str or bytes, not 'list'
```

Here's a copy of the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

 import os
 import shutil
 import sys
 import fnmatch

  root_dir = [d for d in os.listdir(os.curdir) if os.path.isdir(d)]

   work_dir = ['Blaster','Clash','Force','Lockup','PowerOFF','PowerON','Sign1','Spin','Stab','Swing']


   for folder in work_dir:
     os.makedirs(os.path.join(root_dir,folder),exist_ok=True)

  os.chdir(root_dir)

for file in os.listdir('.'):
dst = (work_dir)
if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, 'blaster*'):
      shutil.move(file, dst[0])

if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, 'clash*'):
 shutil.move(file, dst[1])

if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, 'force*'):
 shutil.move(file, dst[2])

if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, 'lockup*'):
 shutil.move(file, dst[3])

if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, 'p*w*off*'):
 shutil.move(file, dst[4])

if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, 'p*w*on*'):
 shutil.move(file, dst[5])

if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, 'combo*'):
 shutil.move(file, dst[6])

if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, 'spin*'):
 shutil.move(file, dst[7])

if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, 'stab*'):
 shutil.move(file, dst[8])

if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, 'swing*'):
 shutil.move(file, dst[9])
```

Please forgive me if this post isn't formatted correctly, as it's my first time posting on Stackoverflow.

Kind regards,

Mike

Comment: `root_dir = [d for d in os.listdir(os.curdir) if os.path.isdir(d)]` is a list comprehension, so what value do you intend it to take in `os.makedirs(os.path.join(root_dir,folder),exist_ok=True)`?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue comes from trying to use `root_dir` in the `.join()`. `root_dir` is a list, as list comprehension returns a list. You'll need to explain further what you're looking for in order for us to help.

Comment: I'm trying to have the script go into each directory and create set of subdirs, then move the files in those directories into the newly created subdirectories.

Comment: @MikeMcNeil See @Alex Hall's answer, that will go through each directory and create the sub-directories you've indicated in your list. You also should also be aware that `os.chdir(root_dir)` should throw an error, as `root_dir` is a list.

Comment: Thanks @Tyler Marques. I modified the script using Alex Hall's suggestion and that portion now works. As for the os.chdir(root_dir) statement, how to I tell the script to 'cd into the list of folders stored in 'root_dir' ?

Comment: You shouldn't need to cd into any of them. Rather you should navigate using the directory names. So your script would be run from the top level, and would look into the directories below and make changes as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want:

```
for root_folder in root_dir:
    for folder in work_dir:
        os.makedirs(os.path.join(root_folder, folder), exist_ok=True)
```